# encoding problem in Python when urlopen() a gbk page

Tags: python, encoding

My code here:

```
# coding:utf-8

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    url = 'http://iccna.blog.sohu.com/164572951.html'
    data = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,fromEncoding='gb18030')
    print WebExtractor(soup)
```

but when debugging, the data like this:

```
��5h�,��4�H�5��VM��\
```

what should i do to get right data for BeautifulSoup? Thanks!

Comment: How are you viewing the data?

Comment: from the variables panel of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the server returns the data compressed by Gzip. Try this:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

import gzip
import StringIO
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://iccna.blog.sohu.com/164572951.html'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
data = StringIO.StringIO(data)
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data)
html = gzipper.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, fromEncoding='gbk')
print(soup)
```

The Chinese characters look still wrong on my system, but this may give you right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works!
i've tried gzip before,but maybe i used it in wrong way.
my code is:
import gzip
gzip.decompress(data)