# How to return plain text from Beautiful Soup instead of unicode

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup4 to scrape this web page, however I'm getting the weird unicode text that BeautifulSoup returns.

Here is my code:

```
    site = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+a+"_"+str(b)
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)  
    req.add_header('Accept-enconding', 'gzip') #Header to check for gzip
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    if page.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip': #IF checks gzip
        data = page.read()
        data = StringIO.StringIO(data)
        gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data)
        html = gzipper.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, fromEncoding='gbk')
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    section = soup.find('span', id='Events').parent
    events = section.find_next('ul').find_all('li')
    print soup.originalEncoding
    for x in events:
        print x
```

Bascially I want x to be in plain English. I get, instead, things that look like this:

```
<li><a href="/wiki/153_BC" title="153 BC">153 BC</a> â€“ <a href="/wiki/Roman_consul" title="Roman consul">Roman consuls</a> begin their year in office.</li>
```

There's only one example in this particular string, but you get the idea.

Related: I go on to cut up this string with some regex and other string cutting methods, should I switch this to plain text before or after I cut it up? I'm assuming it doesn't matter but seeing as I'm defering to SO anyways, I thought I'd ask.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

EDIT: Thanks J.F. for the tip, I now used this after my for loop:

```
    for x in events:
        x = x.encode('ascii')
        x = str(x)
        #Find Content
        regex2 = re.compile(">[^>]*<")
        textList = re.findall(regex2, x)
        text = "".join(textList)
        text = text.replace(">", "")
        text = text.replace("<", "")
        contents.append(text)
```

However, I still get things like this:

```
2013 &#8211; At least 60 people are killed and 200 injured in a stampede after celebrations at F&#233;lix Houphou&#235;t-Boigny Stadium in Abidjan, Ivory Coast.
```

EDIT:
Here is how I make my excel spreadsheet (csv) and send in my list

```
rows = zip(days, contents)
with open("events.csv", "wb") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

So the csv file is created during the program and everything is imported after the lists are generated. I just need to it to be readable text at that point.

Comment: `fromEncoding='gbk'`: why do you use that? Are you sure that the data you are receiving is encoded with that method? (Wikipedia about GBK: "GBK is an extension of the GB2312 character set for simplified Chinese characters")

Comment: And why would you in one case specify the source encoding (`BeautifulSoup(html, fromEncoding='gbk')`) and in the other not (`soup = BeautifulSoup(page)`)?

Comment: Btw, `fromEncoding` has been renamed to `from_encoding`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Wikipedia uses `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` everywhere. *This* is the source encoding you should specify, not gbk.

Comment: I used that by suggestion from someone else, that if statement is supposed to handle gzipped files, is that not what it does?...

Comment: Oh, I was already expecting that this is a mixture of things you found on the web :-) You really should understand what you are doing there, start with reading about text encodings.

Comment: I assume you are scrapping this [webpage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1). Are you doing that on Windows with CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is no such thing as plain text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). What you see are bytes interpreted as text using incorrect character encoding i.e., the encoding of the strings is different from the one used by your terminal unless the error were introduced earlier by using incorrect character encoding for the web page.

`print x` calls `str(x)` that returns UTF-8 encoded string for BeautifulSoup objects.

Try:

```
print unicode(x)
```

Or:

```
print x.encode('ascii')
```

Comment: @AlexChumbley: it is expected output. BeautifulSoup converts non-ascii characters to [numeric character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference).

Comment: Okay, cool, then is there a way to get around that so that it will display normally in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @AlexChumbley: Find out what character encoding your spreadsheet program expects the csv file to be encoded and use it while saving the csv file. Don't convert to ascii in this case, work with Unicode strings internally.

Answer (score 4):

`fromEncoding` (which has been renamed to `from_encoding` for compliance with PEP8) tells the parser how to interpret the data in the input. What you (your browser or urllib) receive from the server is just a stream of bytes. In order to make sense of it, i.e. in order to build a sequence of abstract characters from this stream of bytes (this process is called decoding), one has to *know* how the information was encoded. This piece of information is *required* and you have to provide it in order to make sure that your code behaves properly. Wikipedia tells you how they encode the data, it's stated right at the top of the source of each of their web pages, e.g.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Hence, the bytestream received from Wikipedia's web servers should be interpreted with the UTF-8 codec. You should invoke

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, from_encoding='utf-8')
```

instead of `BeautifulSoup(html, fromEncoding='gbk')`, which tries to decode the bytestream with some Chinese character codec (I guess you blindly copied that piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5416632/145400)).

You really need to make sure that you understand the basic concept of text encodings. Actually, you *want* unicode in the output, which is an abstract representation of a sequence of characters/symbols. In this context, there is no such thing as "plain English".

Comment: +1 for finding the source of my copied code, also thanks for the explanation on how the whole process works