# How to remove nonAscii characters in python

Tags: python, html, character-encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
#!C:/Python27/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys
import urlparse
import io

url = "http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/beel/11beel.html"
#url = "http://eqa.unibo.it/article/view/4554"
#r = requests.get(url)
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

if url.find("http://www.dlib.org") != -1:
    div = soup.find('td', valign='top')
else:
    div = soup.find('div',id='content')

f = open('path/file_name.html', 'w')
f.write(str(div))
f.close()
```

Scraping those webpages i've found some nonAScii characters into the html file written from this script that i need to remove or solve into a readable chars.
Any advice? Thanks

Comment: the script you wrote does not throw any errors, what is the problem with non ascii letters?, do you now want it in the file you are writing?

Comment: I know there are no errors, but there are some characters just like "Â" into the HTML that i need to remove.

Comment: @Poggio may be this will be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732695/how-to-return-plain-text-from-beautiful-soup-instead-of-unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

characters are 8 byte (0-255), ascii chars are 7 byte (0-127), so you can simply drop all chars with a ord value below 128

chr convert a integer to a character, ord converts a character to an integer.

```
text = ''.join((c for c in str(div) if ord(c) < 128)
```

this should be your final code

```
#!C:/Python27/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys
import urlparse
import io

url = "http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/beel/11beel.html"
#url = "http://eqa.unibo.it/article/view/4554"
#r = requests.get(url)
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

if url.find("http://www.dlib.org") != -1:
    div = soup.find('td', valign='top')
else:
    div = soup.find('div',id='content')

f = open('path/file_name.html', 'w')
text = ''.join((c for c in str(div) if ord(c) < 128)
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pppp.py", line 38, in <module>
    div = ''.join((c for c in div if ord(c) < 128))
  File "pppp.py", line 38, in <genexpr>
    div = ''.join((c for c in div if ord(c) < 128))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but Tag found

This is the error

Comment: there should be a str(div), to convert the div tag to a text string, I forgot that

Comment: There are some chars i need to handle in a better way, just like the stressed letters. For example: à - è - ì - ò - ù, that i need to print with the rest of the text. Do you know if there is a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try to normalize the string and then `ASCII` encode it ignoring errors.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unicodedata import normalize

string = 'úäô§'

if isinstance(string, str):
    string = string.decode('utf-8')

print normalize('NFKD', string).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
>>> uao
```

Comment: I think your solution is the best, because my solution does wierd things to 16 bit encoded letters, where yours behave slightly more sane

Answer (score -2):

To remove non `ASCII` characters from text.

```
import string

text = [word for word in text if word not in string.ascii_letters]
```

Comment: This throws errors, cause i can't write nonAscii char into the Python.

Comment: @Poggio you can't run this list comprehension? what are the errors that you a getting ?