# Python - remove unwanted characters from a string

Tags: python

I have string like below Which contains non ascii characters and other special characters:

```
 â€œProjected Set-tled Balan&ceâ€ 456$
```

How to remove all those unwanted characters and get a clean string like below which only has only small or capital alphabets and numbers.

```
  Project Settled Balance 456
```

I'm trying to achieve it with the help of regex `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` I'm expecting a way to return string which matches this regex:

```
pat = re.compile('^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+')
stripped_string = string.strip().lower()
print(stripped_string)
print(pat.match(stripped_string))
```

But this is not returning anything.

Comment: You can check whether each character in the string is alphanumeric with `isalnum()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not regex as you haven't asked it for before

```
''.join([i if ((i == " " )or (ord(i) < 128 and ord(i) >46)) else '' for i in 'â€œProjected Set-tled Balan&ceâ€ 456$'])
```

Updated for regex

```
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+','', 'â€œProjected Set-tled Balan&ceâ€ 456$')
```

Answer (score 0):

`aString.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

My bad, that was pretty dumb of me

Do that but one letter at a time and if you get a error, replace that char with an empty string.

This was asked a lot, but here's these.

[How to remove nonAscii characters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263669/how-to-remove-nonascii-characters-in-python)

[Replace non-ASCII characters with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078816/replace-non-ascii-characters-with-a-single-space)

Comment: This is not providing the desired output.