# How to find url without using href in the below code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-re

```
import requests as rs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

site = 'https://www.iciciprulife.com/'
req = rs.get(site)
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
link=input("Enter which url you want http or https:")

if link == "http":
    for i in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        print(i.get('href'))
```

In The above code I don't want to use 'href' or 'a' instead I want to search URL using regular expression in entire webpage

Comment: You should say **why** you don't want to use href? Using your own regex to parse html is generally considered a bad idea...

Comment: Use an attribute = value css selector

Answer (score 0):

soup.text turns soup to string. This string contains non-ASCII characters, so you need to convert/remove them first.

Then, you can search the whole string with regex.

To remove non-ASCII characters from string:

[How to remove nonAscii characters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33263669/12992521)

Answer (score 0):

```
urls = re.findall(r'https?://[^\s<>"]+', req.text)
```