# Python BeautifulSoup read webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello all…I want to read the “MOST POPULAR” column on http://www.nydailynews.com/.

The codes in Chrome looks like below:

[image]

So I do:

```
url = "http://www.nydailynews.com/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

print soup.find_all(id = 'most-read-content')
```

but it returns nothing.

What’s wrong here? Is it because the “MOST POPULAR” actually a flash or something?

Thanks.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, it give source codes of the page, contains what I want  inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Thee problem is that the server returns the data compressed by Gzip."

Reference below:

[encoding problem in Python when urlopen() a gbk page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415503/encoding-problem-in-python-when-urlopen-a-gbk-page)

Answer (score 0):

The problem begins earlier, with downloading the actual text.
Following your code, `page.read()`
returns a blank result

The first line of page's source code includes `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` but either that's not true or the code isn't set to read utf-8